# How to use namelist in pgdbg

Tags: debugging, fortran

I am trying to debug my program by pgdbg which read in a namelist file at the beginning. But I don't know how to run pgdbg with namelist. I usually execute my program in Linux by:

```
./biomass_mapping < moz2cb05.inp
```

For pgdbg, in the command line, I tried:

```
pgdbg biomass_mapping < moz2cb05.inp
```

The program doesn't execute. I also tried other ways. None of them worked. So does pgdbg work for namelist?

thanks,

Comment: the command seems doen't work. pgdbg stuck in reading the namelist and won't go ahead. What is wrong?

Comment: if you are stuck, consider modifying the fortran to read from a file instead of stdin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure at all of the above since I don't have pgdbg to test it, however, according to [it's documentation](http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgdbgug.pdf), the solution is as follow:

```
$ pgdbg biomass_mapping
....
pgdbg> run < moz2cb05.inp
```

The relevant documentation snippet is:

```
ru[n] [arg0 arg1 ... argn] [< inputfile] [> outputfile] Execute program from the
      beginning. If arguments arg0, arg1, and so on are specified, they are set
      up as the command-line arguments of the program. Otherwise, the arguments
      for the previous  run command are used.
```